# using pdblp with currency option

Tags: bloomberg

I want to use PDBLP to return historic market cap for a stock, which I can do with the code below:

```
df = con.bdh('BHP AU Equity', 'CUR_MKT_CAP','20180129', '20180129')
```

Does anyone know how to include a currency option so that the returned data is in USD? I have tried below using notes from the GitHub site.

```
df = con.bdh('BHP AU Equity', 'CUR_MKT_CAP','20180129', '20180129',elms=[('Currency','USD')])
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `Currency` with `FX` or `EQY_FUND_CRNCY`?

Comment: thanks. it was the 'Currency' field that needed to be all small caps 'currency'. thanks for your help.

Comment: @BrendanS you are a good soul for posting this.